# Android Mediarecorder: How to add new codec in MPEG_4 or any audio format

Tags: java, android, mp4, codec, voice

I written an app for recording voice with Mediarecorder.

```
public void Record(int t)
    {


        final int time = t * 1000;
        Thread sound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(check_start == false)
                {
                    check_start = true;
                    String temp = System.currentTimeMillis()  +".3gpp";
                    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecorder/"+ temp;
                    myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                    try
                    {
                    start();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error in start recording = " + e.toString());
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(time);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {}
                    check_start = false;
                    try
                    {
                        stop();

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error in stop recording = " + e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }
        });
       sound.start();
    }
```

I send time to this function for record Mic.
When I'm recording a minute with this format and coded my file recorded size is 112K. It is very large for me.
Can any one help me for add new codec for reduce file size?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This file size seems quite normal to me, but you can control the output file size by changing the encoding bitrate.

```
MediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate();
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiu! I'm still learning the how to correctly comment on SO